# Is it possible to add new available routes (based on markers) into a mapbox? We are using the javascript sdk

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

We have a private area that does not have any route in it and we would like to connect some markers as a new possible route. Is it possible to do that using mapbox javascript sdk?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We need to create route within a park that does not have one....

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to use JavaScript to enrich the Mapbox Directions API.